# Bad reduction of normalization of singular curve $5y^2=x^4-17$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $C$ be a projective curve defined by $5y^2=x^4-17$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ and $C'$ be its normalization(N.B. $C$ is singular at infinity).

I want to determine in which prime $p$, $C'$ has bad reduction.
$C’$ should be elliptic curve, but I don't have explicit equation of $C'$, so cannot calculate its discriminant.
But to determine bad primes, I need to calculate discriminant some how.

What is standard approach of this kind of problem ?
Thank you for your help.

**P.S.**

The curve $C'$ is binational to the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3-\frac{68}{25} x$.So $C'$ is genus $1$ curve. But binational map does not keep discriminant, so this elliptic curve isn't useful for calculating bad primes.

Comment: You can just go do the computation. See [here on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239746/birationally-transforming-a-quartic-elliptic-curve) for one method.

Comment: Is discriminant invariant under birational map ?

Comment: Discriminat changes under birational, so I think I cannot apply result of your linked page.

Comment: Primes of bad reduction have to be calculated after finding an integral model with minimal discriminant, so even if your equation was an elliptic curve already you may have to do some extra work like changing coordinates and reducing the discriminant.

Comment: Thank you. But even if you get integral model with minimal discriminant of elliptic curve, this does not help finding primes of bad reduction of original curve, because smoothness is not invariant under binational map, I think.

Comment: Yeah, but that's the point, you need to find the normalization, which is birational to your curve (plus, note that for smooth curves, a birational map is actually an honest isomorphism). It sounds like you have a lot more confusions than your post has indicated. It would be helpful for future readers and potential answerers if you added more context, especially around your experience in this area and what you know. Good luck!